# show image in image control in c sharp windows phone 8 using uri

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have image link like http://images.test.com/profiles/profile_28044497_75sq_1359604729.jpg"
now i want to add this image in image control in c sharp in windows phone 8.
I have included using System.Windows.Media but i can't get Bitmapimage class

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following `using` statement:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

Then

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://images.test.com/profiles/profile_28044497_75sq_1359604729.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```